# Пользовательский кросс-браузерный курсор

Tags: javascript, css

http://htmlbook.ru/css/cursor - вроде как поставил курсор на сайт. Работает везде, кроме ИЕ и Оперы. Как заставить курсор работать и в этих обозревателях? Есть ли какие-то хуки для этой реализации. Просьба отписать, даже если нету.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего, в CSS указать самый незаметный из имеющихся курсоров(чаще всего это точка), а за этой точкой таскать картинку.

Comment: А из стандартных самый незаметный - crosshair... Или есть точка какая-то???

Comment: Из совсем стандартных - да. =)

Comment: Из совсем - это как?? Есть ещё какие-то несовсем стандартные??? которые работают во всех браузерах... Потому как если прописывать адрес к точке - то почему бы сразу не прописать адрес к курсору тому что надо...

Comment: Нет. Способов, которые работают во всех(кроме флэши) нет.
Есть всяческие извращения, вроде смещенного курсора(незаметный крестик пользователь не замечает), но они уж очень левые.
Не парьтесь насчет этого: на странице есть куча вещей, которые можно улучшить, кроме курсора:)
Не дело это, элемент управления трогать